# luajit segmentation fault - not in lua-5.2

Tags: c, lua, luajit

hello i am trying to switch to luajit.
the code below compiles and runs fine when using liblua5.2.
when trying to compile and link against luajit-2.0 - it compiles fine but segfaults

has anyone a hint for me?

compile 5.2:

```
gcc -g -O0 -I/usr/include/lua5.2/ -llua5.2 -o lua_sample lua_sample.c
```

compile luajit-2.0

```
 gcc -Wall -I/usr/local/include/luajit-2.0/ -lluajit-5.1 -o luajit_sample lua_sample.c
```

Output on 5.2:

```
# ./lua_sample 
LUA: MAIN
Script ended with 22
LUA: ######## HOOK CALLED - Start
LUA: # service_id: 322
LUA: # service_name: sssasdf
LUA: #     setting new state to 4
SET_STATUS: Service Object: sssasdf
SET_STATUS: Code: 4
LUA: #    call returned RES:-123
LUA: ######## HOOK CALLED - END
HOOK ended with -123
```

output on luajit:

```
# ./luajit_sample 
LUA: MAIN
Segmentation fault
```

lua_sample.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include "lua.h"
#include "lualib.h"
#include "lauxlib.h"

/* the Lua interpreter */

struct service {
    int service_id;
    char service_name[50];
};

static int lua_print(lua_State *L) {
    int i;
    int nargs = lua_gettop(L);

     for (i=1; i <= nargs; ++i) {
        printf("LUA: %s\n",  lua_tostring(L, i));
    }   

}
static int lua_callback_service_set_status(lua_State *L) {
    int status;
    struct service * svc;


    svc=lua_touserdata(L, 1);
    status=lua_tonumber(L, 2);

    printf("SET_STATUS: Service Object: %s\n", svc->service_name);
    printf("SET_STATUS: Code: %d\n",status);

    lua_pushnumber(L, -123);
    return 1;
}

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    int res;
    lua_State* L;


    struct service svc = {
        .service_id=322,
        .service_name="sssasdf"
    };

    /* initialize Lua */    
    L = luaL_newstate();

    /* load various Lua libraries */
    luaL_openlibs(L);

    lua_register(L, "callback_service_set_status", lua_callback_service_set_status);
    lua_register(L, "print", lua_print);



    /* run the script */
    luaL_dostring(L, "return dofile('sample.lua')");


    res = lua_tonumber(L, -1);
    printf("Script ended with %d\n", res);


    /* the function name */
    lua_getglobal(L, "callback_service_finish_hook");


    lua_pushlightuserdata(L, (void*)&svc );


    lua_newtable(L);

    lua_pushliteral(L, "service_id" );
    lua_pushnumber(L, svc.service_id );
    lua_settable(L, -3);  


    lua_pushliteral(L, "service_name" );
    lua_pushstring(L, svc.service_name );
    lua_settable(L, -3);  





    if(lua_pcall(L, 2, 1, 0) != 0 ) {

        printf("error running function `callback_service_finish_hook': %s\n", lua_tostring(L, -1));

    } else {
        /* get the result */    
        res = (int)lua_tonumber(L, -1);
        lua_pop(L, 1);
        printf("HOOK ended with %d\n", res);
    }


    /* print the result */






    /* cleanup Lua */
    lua_close(L);

    return 0;
}
```

sample.lua (in same folder)

```
function callback_service_finish_hook(svc_obj, svc_table) 
    print("######## HOOK CALLED - Start")
    print("# service_id: " ..  svc_table["service_id"])
    print("# service_name: " ..  svc_table["service_name"])
    print("#       setting new state to 4")
    r = callback_service_set_status(svc_obj, 4)
    print("#    call returned RES:" .. r)
    print("######## HOOK CALLED - END")
    return r
end


print("MAIN")
return 22
```

Comment: To narrow down where the crash happens, first build a debug-version of the program (add the `-g` flag when building), then run it in a debugger. The debugger will stop at the location of the crash, and let you examine the function call stack. Look at the call-stack, and if the crash is not in your code then walk up the call-stack until you are in your code. There you can examine values of variables to see if they look to be what you expect them to be. If nothing else, please edit your question to show where (in your code) the crash happens.

Comment: did that    -g -O0 but gdb just says startup program terminated and shows no backtrace

Comment: If the program doesn't crash when you run it in a debugger, then you most likely have an uninitialized pointer. Debugger clear local variables, meaning that pointers become `NULL`. If you check for `NULL` then it will work in the debugger, but as the variable will be uninitialized when not in the debugger its value will be indeterminate (and seemingly random) so the `NULL` check will not catch it, and you will use the uninitialized pointer and have [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). You should check local variables and make sure they are initialized.

Comment: Also note that it might actually be a bug in Lua/Luajit. Try to minimize the code to replicate the problem, and make sure your code is working as it should (a good start is to add more compiler warnings, e.g. `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`). If the crash still happens and your code is as good as it can be, then go to Lua and add a bug report showing the code you have.

Comment: You are not checking the return value from `lua_touserdata()` which can return `NULL` but which you soon dereference.

Comment: hmmm ok - removed the userdata stuff - and still crashes

Comment: `lua_print` has no return type. Try `return 0;`, note `-Wall -pedantic` would have warned you about this.

Comment: "gdb just says startup program terminated" Can you show us all of that session's output? (BTW, your program runs fine on my computer (with luajit).)

Comment: return 0 on lua_print fixed it

Comment: @greatwolf and @joachim-pileborg are right `-Wall -Werror -pedantic` would have shown it - so  how do i mark it as resolved?

Comment: Provide your own answer with a summary and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the `return 0;` in `lua_print()` was missing.
adding this - fixed the segfault.

thx - to all commenters - adding `-Wall -Werror -pedantic` would have shown that the `lua_print()` does not return a value.

so the final lua_print looks like:

```
static int lua_print(lua_State *L) {
    int i;
    int nargs = lua_gettop(L);

    for (i=1; i <= nargs; ++i) {
        printf("LUA: %s\n",  lua_tostring(L, i));
    }   
   return 0;
}
```